# android shell content query error

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to get system settings using `content query` command.
For example:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/system --projection name:value --where "name='user_rotation'"
```

Returns with following error

```
Error while accessing provider:settings
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: user_rotation (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, value F
ROM system WHERE (name=user_rotation)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
        at com.android.commands.content.Content$QueryCommand.onExecute(Content.java:535)
        at com.android.commands.content.Content$Command.execute(Content.java:417)
        at com.android.commands.content.Content.main(Content.java:605)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)
```

I could get all the entries though with,

```
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/system
```

Comment: somewhere the `'` quotes are being lost, and your where clause is executing as `name=user_rotation`, which is comparing two fields - and the db is rightly complaining that `user_rotation` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. When I enter directly in the shell it does work. So I guess the `adb shell` must be doing something with the command.

Comment: It was not `adb shell` but your local shell which stripped the quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar error and found that escaping the inner quotes resolved my issue. Try changing `--where "name='user_rotation'"` to this `--where 'name=\"user_rotation\"'`.

Here's what your updated command should look like:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/system --projection name:value --where 'name=\"user_rotation\"'
```

Hope this helps.